# DQL in config.yml not overwritten in config_test.yml

Tags: php, sqlite, symfony, doctrine-orm

EDIT: Original title" Text environment: "Function "year" does not supported for platform "sqlite""

Incorporating beberlei\DoctrineExtensions in the test environment results in

> Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException: "[Syntax
>   Error] Function "year" does not supported for platform "sqlite""...

`composer show -i` includes

```
beberlei/DoctrineExtensions          v1.0.5
```

The extensions are installed: they exist at "...vendor\beberlei\DoctrineExtensions".

The `month()` function does NOT throw an error.

#### config_test.yml

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: test
        connections:
            test:
                driver:   pdo_sqlite
                path:     %kernel.cache_dir%/test.sqlite
    orm:
        dql:
            string_functions:
                Soundex: Truckee\VolunteerBundle\DQL\Soundex
                month: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Sqlite\Month
            datetime_functions:
                year: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Sqlite\Year
```

#### config.yml DQL

```
    dql:
        string_functions:
            Soundex: Truckee\VolunteerBundle\DQL\Soundex
        numeric_functions:
            month: Oro\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\SimpleFunction
            year: Oro\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\SimpleFunction
```

#### function call

```
public function expiringOppsNotSent()
{
    $nextMonth = date_add(new \DateTime(), new \DateInterval('P1M'));
    $expiryMonth = date_format($nextMonth, 'm');
    $expiryYear = date_format($nextMonth, 'Y');
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select('o')
        ->from('TruckeeVolunteerBundle:Opportunity', 'o')
        ->leftJoin('TruckeeVolunteerBundle:AdminOutbox', 'a', 'WITH', $qb->expr()->eq('a.oppId', 'o'))
        ->andWhere($qb->expr()->eq('month(o.expireDate)', ':month'))
        ->andWhere($qb->expr()->eq('year(o.expireDate)', ':year'))
        ->andWhere('a.id is NULL')
        ->setParameter(':month', $expiryMonth)
        ->setParameter(':year', $expiryYear)
        ;
    $notSent = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();

    return $notSent;
}
```

#### Edit:

The error does not occur if the dql in config.yml (as shown above) are commented out!

#### Edit #2:

Error persists in functional test with `app_dev.php` created.
Functional test uses `Liip\FunctionalTestBundle\Test\WebTestCase`

Comment: Namespace updated per @nifr below.  Error persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wish I had a rational explanation for why the error(s) have disappeared.  I experimented with the order and labeling DQL to no effect.  I deleted and re-entered the entries and now no errors.  Best guess is there was at least one non-display character in an entry.  For now all tests pass in SQLite!

Answer (score 1):

The correct namespace for the Sqlite Plugin is:

```
DoctrineExtensions\Query\Sqlite\Year
```

Update your `config.yml` to include:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        dql:
            datetime_functions:
                year: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Sqlite\Year
```

Comment: Changing the namespace did not remove the error.  (Test cache was deleted before trial. Both month & year were modified)  Note that the entries are made in config_test.yml.  It may be relevant that there are dql entries in config.yml (e.g., `month: Oro\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\SimpleFunction`) that are intended to be overwritten.

Comment: The question has been edited to show that the error occurs only if the DQL in config.yml appear.  When commented out the error disappears.  Shouldn't the DQL in config.yml be overwritten by that in config_test.yml?

Comment: I upvoted your answer - it was necessary to the solution, but not sufficient.